# Event.watch not firing

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm following this very [simple web3 tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/100/Solidity-Events-Tutorial---Using-Web3.js-to-Listen-for-Smart-Contract-Events) and `Event.watch` doesn't seem to fire when I click the button.

I can't figure it out.

Can someone please help?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {

   string fName;
   uint age;

   event Instructor(
       string name,
       uint age
    );

   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
       Instructor(_fName, _age); 
   }
}
```

and then JS:

```
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor();
instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  alert(1);
});
$("#button").click(function() {
  Coursetro.setInstructor('a', 1);
});
```

alert never happens.

Comment: Are you sending a transaction to `setInstructor` and if so, is it being mined?

Comment: What do you mean by sending a transaction? And this is executed on a local testrpc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by specifying the block range given by `fromBlock` and `toBlock` when defining the reference to the event in JS. So for your case, you could try the following:

```
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor({}, {fromBlock: startBlockNo, toBlock: 'latest'});
instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result){
    alert(1);
});
```

Note that only the first line is changed, I added the rest just for completeness.

Comment: @gisdev_p Where are you populating startBlockNo from?

Comment: You can choose it freely, as needed. Some examples: You could set it to the block with that you deployed your smart contract, or to a block that corresponds to a certain date or that covers a certain period in the past. In an case, has to be smaller or equal to the total number of blocks, of course.